# I'm browsing Stack Overflow. Why do I see *first* questions from other communities?

Tags: feature-request

I'm on Stack Overflow, browsing as usual, but today I notice that when I go back to the home page, I get questions that have nothing to do with Stack Overflow.

[image: "Technical Communities Recently Active Questions"]

So basically the message I get is: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please look elsewhere.

I get it, I can collapse, but it's cluttering the visual space, even when collapsed (and it's not collapsed by default)! Look, the *Top Questions* are at the *bottom* of my screen! This seriously give an impression of Google where no one can find where the actual results are. Do you really want to have a landing page as bad as Google's search results page?

Also, I don't care about those questions: I already have the Hot Network Questions box if I want to go outside of Stack Overflow. And the advantage of the HNQ is that at least I'm not limited to "Technical Communities".

I know you want to change the Hot Network Questions. But like this? Taking all my visual space? No. I'm on Stack Overflow, I want to see Stack Overflow questions. Please get rid of this.

Comment: *"Our questions suck. Maybe you'd like these better?"*